# Texture won't load OpenGL ES 2.0 PowerVR SDK

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, powervr-sgx

I am currently having problems with my texture loading using the PVR SDK.  I know that both of my textures have a linear sample filter.  However it fires my message that I have set if a texture load fails.  This is how I load my textures in.

```
const unsigned int NoTex = 3;


     // PVR texture files
const char* const  TextureFile[NoTex]   =
{ "n_Map1.pvr",
  "DUDV_map.pvr",
  "Skybox.pvr"};
```

and here is my method to load in the textures

```
bool OGLES2Skybox2::LoadTextures(CPVRTString* const pErrorStr)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        if(PVRTTextureLoadFromPVR(TextureFile[i], &TextureID[i]) != PVR_SUCCESS){
            *pErrorStr = CPVRTString("ERROR: Could not open texture file ") + TextureFile[i];
            return false;
        }

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    }

    // Load cube maps
    if(PVRTTextureLoadFromPVR(TextureFile[2], &TextureID[2]))
    {
        *pErrorStr = CPVRTString("ERROR: Could not open texture file ") + TextureFile[2];
        return false;
    }

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    return true;
}
```

and after I call LoadTextures in my initView method()

```
 bool OGLES2Skybox2::InitView()
    {
        // Sets the clear colour
        glClearColor(0.6f, 0.8f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        // Enables depth test using the z-buffer
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        CPVRTString ErrorStr;

        /*
            Load textures
        */
        if(!LoadTextures(&ErrorStr))
        {
            PVRShellSet(prefExitMessage, ErrorStr.c_str());
            return false;
        }
    ...
    }
```

Comment: There can be 2 types of headers of PVR files - the new and the legacy headers. You can try re-saving your textures in both ways. Please google for "PVRTextool save as legacy" for more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry my fault.  The reason was that I used the PVR FileWrap tool and since the content was already binded to the application and had automatically generated a .cpp file I had forgot to add the .cpp's back into the project.